# Selenium-wire errors while runing my tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, ssl-certificate, pytest

When I run my Selenium automated tests suits using Python and Pytest, with the library Selenium-wire to access the requests and making assertions about them I get the following errros for every single test run:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64277/devtools/browser/45752844-8253-493e-a10e-75b31a3b2dce
```

[0813/205047.956:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for staging.admin.convercus.io failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205048.750:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for unpkg.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205050.405:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for fonts.googleapis.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205050.648:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for o146990.ingest.sentry.io failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205050.847:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for staging.convercus.io failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205050.848:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for staging.convercus.io failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205051.271:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for fonts.gstatic.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205053.887:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for [www.googletagmanager.com](http://www.googletagmanager.com) failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205053.916:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for firebasestorage.googleapis.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205053.947:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for d29l98y0pmei9d.cloudfront.net failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205054.959:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for region1.google-analytics.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205055.246:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for convercus.supporthero.io failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[0813/205055.248:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for convercus.supporthero.io failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

Coupon creation Test nº20 - Reward Campaign
[0813/205103.885:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://staging.admin.convercus.io/_nuxt/285572a7272e0f5cf8a4.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://staging.admin.convercus.io/con/coupons3/add?type=REWARD&assignation_type=CAMPAIGN (0)
[0813/205103.885:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://staging.admin.convercus.io/_nuxt/fb3ac4e2e62a331ac0ac.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

NOTE: My tests pass regardless of this but it takes twice as much or more now since it processes those errors for each test

Comment: _Selenium_ or _selenium-wire_?

Comment: Selenium with selenium-wire. Sorry I´m a junior needing help